# Git undo revert

Tags: eclipse, git

I am using Eclipse. And, today, I decided to push all the code I wrote during two weeks. However, I did a mistake in the message of the commit with all my changes, so I clicked on the but "Revert" of the Git perspective of Eclipse. But, all the code I wrote during these two weeks is not anymore in the working tree!

So, I did `git log` and got this:

```
commit dd2401c076f4e34f2bdfb642f0ef4ab1dc476458
Date:   Sun Jul 16 15:03:40 2017 +0100

Revert "Rewrited the Linear Plan Tree. Renamed the planner/node package to"

This reverts commit 9240fd696fbe827e58a8eb827014125b7b1b5bb1.

commit 9240fd696fbe827e58a8eb827014125b7b1b5bb1
Date:   Sun Jul 16 15:02:20 2017 +0100

Rewrited the Linear Plan Tree. Renamed the planner/node package to
```

So, I executed this command: `git reset --soft HEAD~1`.

But, in my file explorer, all the files I wrote are still removed and now, `git log` shows me:

```
commit 9240fd696fbe827e58a8eb827014125b7b1b5bb1
Author: Lucas Willems <lwillems@clipper.ens.fr>
Date:   Sun Jul 16 15:02:20 2017 +0100

Rewrited the Linear Plan Tree. Renamed the planner/node package to
```

Is my code deleted forever? Is there a way to get it back? Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: what does `git status` show?

Comment: By the way, since you *do* have the hash ID for cut-and-paste, it's easier than digging around in the reflogs: `git reset --hard 9240fd696fbe827e58a8eb827014125b7b1b5bb1` will do the job. But do read my whole answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my code deleted forever?

No.  You *committed* some file content; the committed content is retrievable.  Even "deleting a commit" doesn't actually delete it immediately, in Git, due to what Git calls its *reflogs*.

Note that *uncommitted* content is much harder to retrieve, which is why people say that you should commit early and often.

#### Commits, index, and work-tree; or, `git reset` is a tricky command to explain

> Is there a way to get it back?

Yes!  But it takes a bit of patience to get there. :-)

The first step is to get a clear visualization of the three "parts" that Git keeps visible—well, somewhat—at all times, in each repository.  When you used `git reset --soft` you told Git to *separate* some of these parts.

These three parts are the *current commit*, which is also known as `HEAD`; the *index*, which is also called the *staging area* and the *cache*; and the *work-tree* or *working tree*, which is the only one of the three that you can actually *see* when you look around at your computer.

Of these three, the one that is easy to see—the work-tree—doesn't actually matter to Git! :-)  (We'll "see" the other two indirectly all the time, via `git status`.  Seeing the index directly is a bit tricky: try `git ls-files --stage` someday.  Seeing the `HEAD` commit directly is also tricky: try `git ls-tree -r HEAD`, for instance.)

One of these three entites, the commit, is read-only.  When you make a commit, it is (mostly) permanent (under some conditions, you can make it go away) and it never changes after that.  Its "true name" is one of those big ugly Git hash IDs, `09baf31...` or whatever.  As long as it exists in your repository, you can name it by this hash ID, e.g.:

```
git show 09baf31
```

for instance.  But note that `git show` *shows* it by *comparing* it to something—you "show" a commit in a certain context.

When you *check out* a commit, you ask Git to copy it to those other two places, the *index* and the *work-tree*.

The *index* is how Git builds *new* commits.  When you run `git commit`, whatever is in the index *right now*, goes into the new commit.  And yet, you cannot easily see what is in the index right now!  What you *can* do is have Git compare the *current* commit to the index, and tell you what's *different*.  The `git status` command does that.

To *change what's in the index*, you will generally work on the *third* copy of each file, i.e., the one in your work-tree.  You do your actual work in your work-tree, where you can see your files, and work on them.  Then you run `git add <file>` to *copy from the work-tree to the index*.

The `git status` command compares *everything*:

```
HEAD version        index version       work-tree version
------------        -------------       -----------------
README.md           README.md           README.md
file.txt            file.txt            file.txt
```

Note again that there are *three versions of every file*.  (The HEAD and index versions are kept in special compressed formats, so this does not take that much space.)  The `HEAD` version is read-only, but you can copy any other version back or forward: from HEAD to index, from index to work-tree, and from work-tree to index.

Again, **commits are the only *permanent* part of this whole process.** Whatever is in the index and work-tree is *temporary*; the index is used to *make new commits*, and the work-tree is just there for you to mess with things, so that you can copy them into the index.

#### The commit graph

Each commit—the part of Git that stores files permanently—has one of those big ugly hash IDs we noted.  It also carries the idea, or more precisely, the hash ID, of a *parent commit*.  The *parent* of a commit is Git's way of remembering what was committed *before* that commit.

The very first commit you make in a repository is special because it has no parent.  (It can't, it's the *first!*)  We call this a *root* commit.  After that, each new commit remembers its parent.  We say that each commit "points back to" its parent:

```
A <-B <-C
```

The way Git finds commits is to start from the *newest* one, which it remembers by a branch name like `master`.  We say that the branch name `master` points to the *tip* commit of the branch:

```
A <-B <-C   <-- master
```

Each commit then points back to some earlier commit, which points back again, and so on.  The whole process only stops when we reach the root commit (`A` in the drawing above), or when we get tired of `git log` output and stop looking. :-)

Let's say the current commit is `C`.  This means that `master` *points to* `C`.  The name `HEAD` refers to `master`, because we're on our `master` branch.  The index and work-tree have copies of what's in commit `C`.  *All three copies of every file match*, so `git status` just says:

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

The first part, `on branch master`, is from the fact that `HEAD` says `master`.  That's how Git knows that commit `C` is the current commit: it reads `HEAD`, which says `master`; then it reads `master`, which has the hash ID for commit `C`; then it looks inside commit `C` as needed.

The second part says that the index matches the HEAD commit, and the work-tree matches the index.  All three copies of every file are all identical.

#### Making new commits

To add a new commit, we might change one of our files, such as `file.txt`, so that it has a change in the work-tree.  Then we `git add file.txt`, so that the index copy gets updated.  Now `git status` compares HEAD vs index and sees that `file.txt` is ready to be committed.  It also compares index vs work-tree and says there's nothing else to `git add`, so we're ready to commit.  We run `git commit` and Git makes a new commit `D` using the files that are in the index, sets `D`'s parent to `C`, and—this is the really tricky bit—*changes the name `master`* so that `master` now points to new commit `D`:

```
A <-B <-C <-D   <-- master
```

The `HEAD` file itself doesn't change (it still just says `master`), but now the HEAD commit is commit `D`.  The HEAD commit matches the index, because of course it does, we just *made* this commit *from* the index.  The index matches the work-tree, because we didn't change either of those.  So now all three match, and everything is normal!

#### Showing a commit, in context

Since each commit remembers its *previous* (parent) commit, when you go to look at one, with `git show` or `git log -p`, Git compares the content stored under the two commit hashes: the parent, vs the commit itself.  It then shows you only what *changed* between those two.

Each commit has a full, complete copy of everything, but when you use `git show` to *see* it, Git shows you "what changed from parent to child", because that's usually more *useful* to know.

#### A brief look at `git revert`

What `git revert` does is pretty simple, really.  This somewhat poorly named command looks at some—any—*existing* commit to see what it changed, just like `git show` does.  Then, starting from the *current* commit, Git tries to make a new change that "undoes" whatever the selected commit did.  If the commit you're reverting added a line to a file, Git removes that line from that file.  If the commit you're reverting removed two lines from a second file, Git puts those two lines into that second file.

If all of this works, `git revert` makes a new commit with the result.  The parent of the new commit is the current commit.  This lets you back out *any* previous commit, not just the last one, as long as Git can figure out how to "undo" what that previous commit did.

Let's draw that in:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD)
```

I'm going to stop drawing the internal arrows: just remember they're *all backwards* all the time, as Git works backwards.  We add the `(HEAD)` or some similar notation to keep track of which *branch name* is in HEAD.

#### What `git reset` does

What `git reset` does is complicated.

The first step is that it *moves a branch name*.  You pick the commit you want, and this is where your `HEAD~1` came in.  If you had:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and you write `HEAD~1`, Git counts one commit back from `HEAD`.  Since `HEAD` locates commit `D`, this makes Git count back one step to commit `C`.

Git then makes the actual branch name point to that commit:

```
        D
       /
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
```

What happened to commit `D`?  Well, *nothing* really: it's still there.  It's just shoved aside, because we need to show that `master` now points to `C`, not to `D`.

The next step for `git reset` *would be* to copy the new HEAD commit's contents to the index.  But if you say `--soft`, you tell it: no, don't touch the index; just do the first step, of making the branch name point somewhere different, and then stop.

If you had used `git reset --mixed`, Git would have re-set the index, by making it match the new HEAD commit.  It would then stop at that point: HEAD and index would match, but the work-tree would be left untouched.

If you had used `git reset --hard`, Git would keep going: it would *also* re-set the work-tree, from the index that it just got from the new HEAD commit.

#### Putting this all together

Now, what you want, in this case, is to have your index and work-tree match what's in commit `C`.  What you should have done originally is `git reset --hard HEAD~1`, but **don't do that now**, because now `master` already points to `C`!

But: What if, instead of moving the name `master`, you tell `git reset` to "move" from commit `C` to commit `C`?  You would do this with `git reset HEAD`, i.e., the place to move `master` is wherever it is now.  You can even leave out the `HEAD` part, since that's the default.  You can then *also* tell `git reset` to re-set the index and the work-tree:

```
git reset --hard
```

This wipes out the current index, replacing it with whatever is in the selected commit (`C` in the diagram, or whatever it really is in your repository).  Then it replaces the work-tree contents with the new index contents too, and now all three are back in sync, just like normal!

#### But, uh oh, you ran `git reset --hard HEAD~1`.  Enter the reflogs!

Well, let's go back to the diagram:

```
       D
      /
     C
    /
A--B   <-- master (HEAD)
```

What you need now is to get commit `C` back.  It's still *in there*, shoved up out of the way; it's just *hard to find* now.

You need to find a way to *name* commit `C`: e.g., its hash ID, or some alternative that will work.  This is where the reflogs come in.

Commits `C` and `D` above don't have anything pointing to them.  This is because they don't have a *branch name*.  Fortunately, Git keeps the *previous* values of each branch around for 30 days by default.  If you run:

```
git reflog master
```

Git will spill out all the old hash IDs (abbreviated) and these funny `master@{1}`, `master@{2}`, and so on names.

The name `HEAD` itself also has a reflog; `git reflog` will show those.  The `HEAD` reflog changes fastest, because it's constantly being updated, so I like to use the other ones if possible, but it's up to you.

Once you have the hash ID, you can cut and paste it.  Or, if the names aren't changing too fast, you can use the `@{1}` style names.  This is what they *probably* look like right now:

```
       D   master@{2}, HEAD@{2}
      /
     C   master@{1}, HEAD@{1}
    /
A--B   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Note that the numbers themselves increment every time you make a change.  So if `master@{1}` names commit `C` *right now*, you can now run:

```
git reset --hard master@{1}
```

(though you might have to add some quote marks, e.g., `git reset --hard "master@{1}"` with the quotes, depending on your shell).  That will do yet another `reset`, moving the name `master` to point to `C` again.

Or, you can run `git reflog`, look for the right commit, cut and paste its hash ID, and use `git reset --hard <hash-id>`.

Eventually—some time after the 30 day expiration—Git will *expire* some of the old numbers, like `master@{912}` or whatever, and once that happens, any commits that are all dangly-off-the-edges like that may get *garbage collected*.  So don't wait more than 30 days to get them back.

#### Conclusion (since this is long)

Commit early and often.  The *commits* are permanent, unless reset, but even then they stick around for a while.  Be careful with `git reset`: although the commits still stick around for 30 days, they can become very hard to *find*.  Also, `git reset --hard` will overwrite your work-tree, and even `git reset --mixed` will overwrite your index.  Remember, the index is *where you build the next commit*, and your work-tree is where you work on files.

Comment: I didn't thank you by the time for this so detailed answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have run `git reset --hard HEAD~1` intead of "soft". "Soft" means that working vopy and index are not updated, so at filesystem ig still looks like reverted. You shoul run `git reset --hard` now. It makes sense to run `git status` and `git diff HEAD` to check if there are some uncommitted changes which you could want to keep

Comment: I did "git reset --hard HEAD~1" and it deleted all the uncommited changes... I am so sad...

Comment: The second `reset` makes things harder.  Fortunately I was mostly done with my writeup and was able to add the reflog descriptions.

Comment: Do `git checkout -b tmp-branch 9240fd696fb` to recover the rewritten Linear Plan Tree code. The mistake was to leave `HEAD~1` as argument to the reset. After `--soft HEAD~1` you've already moved one commit away from the HEAD state of the "Revert Rewrited..." commit

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing the following steps from the Git bash:

```
git stash
git checkout yourBranch
git revert dd2401c0
git stash apply
```

The basic strategy here is to stash your current working directory, and then to revert the revert commit.  Yes, two reverts cancel each other out.

The problem with doing `git reset` here is that it moves the HEAD of your branch.  This appears to have the side effect that any new files you wrote get erased.  In any case, doing a reset would rewrite the history of your branch, which isn't ideal if the branch could be shared by other people.

Comment: I did wait for your answer and did "git reset --hard HEAD~1", but it deleted all the uncommited changes... I am so sad. I think there is no solution to get these changes back...

Comment: @LucasWillems The deleted commits are still available in the reflog.  SO already well covers how to handle this.  If you had followed my suggeated answer this would not have happened.